# Python googleapiclient HTTP 403 Error when downloading: 'cannot download abusive file'

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

For the last few months I've been downloading files off my Google Drive using the googleapiclient in Python, and I haven't had any issues. Today, I am getting this error message on all files I attempt to download:

*HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1EZ2RKHBkVh4uKuyixh1epxb4l7ATHnFx?acknowledgeAbuse=true&alt=media returned "This file has been identified as malware or spam and cannot be downloaded.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'cannotDownloadAbusiveFile', 'message': 'This file has been identified as malware or spam and cannot be downloaded.'}]">*

I've tried setting acknowledgeAbuse to True, as this has been suggested as a way to circumvent the problem, but to no avail, still get same error message. Any help would be magnificent.

````
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import io
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
token = 'C:\\Users\\tomdr\\gsheets_token.json'

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(token, scope)

service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

#find file_id and filestring to download (won't link code, it's just trivial and not an issue)#

request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id, acknowledgeAbuse=True)
fh = io.FileIO(filestring, 'wb') 
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()```
````

Comment: Same issue here as well, started today, using Java google-api-client.  It seems to only happen with certain PDF files that contain images that were converted to a PDF, while other PDF documents are downloaded without issue.

Comment: FYI, found reported bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/238551542

Comment: The error message is now this ...

HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1o7i_V9xuKJrtNZ01mBrQaZrNOAD1dnM0?acknowledgeAbuse=true&alt=media returned "Only the owner can download abusive files.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'cannotDownloadAbusiveFile', 'message': 'Only the owner can download abusive files.', 'locationType': 'parameter', 'location': 'acknowledgeAbuse'}]">

Comment: Google made a fix, which resolved my issue. Of note, my API usage is always fetching files that are owned by the API user, are you fetching files not owned by the user?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is now solved, yesterday it was not working but today the API is back to normal.

Thanks all for the support and help on this.