# Cannot download Excel file through Drive API -

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, drive, google-drive-shared-drive

I am trying to download an Excel file using Drive API. Here is my code:

```
def downloadXlsx(vars, file, creds):
    try:
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
        fileId = file['id']
        fileName = file['name']
        # request = service.files().get_media(fileId=fileId)
        request = service.files().get_media(fileId=fileId, acknowledgeAbuse=True)
        # request = service.files().get(fileId=fileId,   supportsTeamDrives=True, fields='*').execute()

        fh = io.BytesIO()
        downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
        done = False
        while done is False:
            status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
            print("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
        fh.seek(0)
        print('%s%s' % (vars.download_directory, fileName))
        with open('%s%s' % (vars.download_directory, fileName), 'wb') as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(fh, f, length=131072)
    except HttpError as error:
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
```

Every time I run it most files return this error

> An error occurred: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?acknowledgeAbuse=true&alt=media returned "This file has been identified as malware or spam and cannot be downloaded.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'cannotDownloadAbusiveFile', 'message': 'This file has been identified as malware or spam and cannot be downloaded.'}]">

I tried adding the `acknowledgeAbuse=True` flag but it doesn't change anything. Previously it would give me this error:

> An error occurred: <HttpError 403 when requesting
> https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1fr7NwhToKFgvbNgExl0QMgurLJlx8KmV?acknowledgeAbuse=true&alt=media
> returned "Only the owner can download abusive files.". Details:
> "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'cannotDownloadAbusiveFile',
> 'message': 'Only the owner can download abusive files.',
> 'locationType': 'parameter', 'location': 'acknowledgeAbuse'}]">

But I no longer get this error and I'm not sure why as I haven't changed anything.

I tried using this line:

```
   request = service.files().get(fileId=fileId,   supportsTeamDrives=True, fields='*').execute()
```

Which would download the file but it would be corrupted and unable to be opened.

Anyway, does anyone have a clue how I can get around this? Maybe a different method I could try or a way to get the .get() to download the file properly? I don't know why it's saying I'm not the owner - if anyone has knowledge on how Drive API determines 'who' is executing the API that would be helpful.

Edit:
I'm looking at the files.get method documentation here and it reads the following:

> By default, this responds with a Files resource in the response body.
> If you provide the URL parameter alt=media, then the response includes
> the file contents in the response body. Downloading content with
> alt=media only works if the file is stored in Drive. To download
> Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides use files.export instead. For further
> information on downloading files, refer to Download files

Seems like I need to specify alt=media somehow but not sure if that is possible in my situation. Maybe that's referring to get_media?

Comment: Try using `supportAllDrives` for V3. ?

Comment: If this is a Shared Drive, are you impersonating a user from it or directly using a service account? If anything, the sharing permission it has is "Manager"?

Comment: This might be related to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72952434/python-googleapiclient-http-403-error-when-downloading-cannot-download-abusive

Comment: @David Haha wow! That is exactly the bug I was facing! I see that it was reported yesterday and resolved today and sure enough its fixed for me! Amazing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed! It was a bug with Google Drive API. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/238551542

Answer (score 1):

There is an optional parm that you can send with your [file.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) request

> acknowledgeAbuse   boolean Whether the user is acknowledging the risk of downloading known malware or other abusive files. This is only applicable when alt=media. (Default: false)

try

```
request = service.files().get(fileId=fileId,   supportsTeamDrives=True, fields='*', acknowledgeAbuse='true').execute()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The files.get method works without giving me any error responses even if I do not put acknowledgeAbuse='true' but the file I receive does NOT have the actual file data. Instead it is a JSON file which describes the file. 

{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "xxxx",
 "name": "CISD_Comments.xlsx",
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
 "starred": false,
 "trashed": false,
 "explicitlyTrashed": false,
 "parents": [
  "xxxx"
 ],
 "spaces": [
  "drive"
 ],
 "version": "3"
}

for example

Comment: thats just the meta data you need to download the file

Comment: Check manage download docs https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads