# Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError - malware or spam and cannot be downloaded

Tags: google-api, tags, stack, overflow

I am facing an issue when downloading's files from gDrive using API in UIPath

The error is the following:

Download failed after 0 bytes. Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError This file has been identified as malware or spam and cannot be downloaded. [403] Errors [ Message[This file has been identified as malware or spam and cannot be downloaded.] Location[ - ] Reason[cannotDownloadAbusiveFile] Domain[global] ]

Any thoughts on this that comes to mind?

Thanks for all the help

Comment: The error appears clear. If you're able to downloading the file(s) directly using the Drive web client (or some other client) and experiencing inconsistent behavior with the API, then you could report it to Google. If you believe that the files aren't "malware or spam", similarly you will need to report this to Google.

Comment: This could be related to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72952434/python-googleapiclient-http-403-error-when-downloading-cannot-download-abusive